# Generating HL7 file using Chameleon

Tags: hl7, iguana-ui

I want to generate HL7 file v2.5.1 for meaningful Use-2. However my chameleon version is old one (v2.3) and it supports only up to HL7 v2.3.1. Now can i generate HL7 v2.5.1 with existing tool or i will buy new updated version.

Please if know about this guide me thanks.

Comment: Is it giving you some sort of error while attempting to generate 2.5.1 message from chameleon?

Comment: I am asking it is possible or not? Is there any major differences between HL7 v2.3 and HL7 v2.5.1 ?

Comment: So you never made an attempt. Syntactically both are same, not much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

HL7 V2.5.x has some additional fields which were not in previous versions.
So to generate meaningful Use-2 for 2.5.1 you have to update.